# Java and Gradle: split in multiple projects or use different SourceSets?

Tags: java, gradle, project

Imagine an Application/Library project, where the Library is usable by external clients to access the functionalities offered by the application.

With the Gradle build environment, should I use multiple SourceSets/packages to divide the two like

```
src/main/java/app
stc/main/java/lib
```

Or create two different `module`s with two sets of `gradle.build`, `src`, etc. In the latter case, how would I share common classes between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Create 3 modules, `commons`, `client`, `app`.
That makes it easiest to create separate jars. Also gradle build times improve.

Make both `client` and `app` depend on `commons`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':commons') 
}
```

See https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/